# Powers in non-commutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $a,b$ be elements of a non-commutative ring $R$ with $\operatorname{char}(R) =p > 0$ and suppose that $ab-ba=[a,b]=1$. My question is simply:

> Could you give a formula for the element $(a^n b^m)^p$ in the form $\sum\limits_{i,j} c_{ij} a^i b^j$?

For example, $(ab)^2=abab=a(ab-1)b=a^2b^2-ab$. I've tried to find some patterns in order to use induction, but without much success. May be someone more familiar with manipulations like this could help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No doubt this is some nifty combinatorial problem or other with a well-known solution, but brute force can get us some of the way. Using $[A,BC]=[A,B]C+B[A,C]$, it is easy to check that
$$ [b,a^n] = [b,a^{n-1}]a+a^{n-1}[b,a] = [b,a^{n-1}]a-a^{n-1}, $$
and iterating gives us inductively
$$ [b,a^n] = -na^{n-1}. $$

Now, supposing initially that $n\geqslant m$, I believe one can similarly derive the following:
$$ [b^m,a^n] = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} (-1)^{k+1} \binom{m}{k} \frac{n!}{(n-m+k)!} a^{n-m+k} b^k. $$
(if there's a more symmetric way of writing this, I'm happy to hear it...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Chappers! But how can we use the expression for $[b^m,a^n]$ to evaluate $(a^n b^m)^p$?

Comment: At this point, we have to start writing $(a^n b^m)^p = a^n b^m a^n b^m (a^n b^m)^{p-2} = a^n ([b^m, a^n]+a^n b^m) b^m (a^n b^m)^{p-2} $. This looks pretty grim. As an alternative, we could look at $a^n([b^m,(a^n b^m)^{p-1}]+(a^n b^m)^{p-1}b^m)$, and hope that some sort of induction works there as it did on $a^n b^m$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party but I found this question while working on some problem involving $D$-modules so I can share what I have. Actually I did the case $[b,a]=1$ and $R=\mathbb C[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\langle\partial_1,\ldots,\partial_n\rangle$ which has characteristic $0.$ So for me $a=x_i$ and $b=\partial_i.$ It's not exactly what you're looking for but anyway here it is.

The same argument in Chappers' answer shows that $[b,a^n]=na^{n-1}$ (the sign change coming from the opposite commutator condition).

We go by induction. Assume we have $(ab)^n=\sum_{k=1}^n c_{n,k}a^kb^k.$ Then
\begin{align*}(ab)^{n+1}&=\sum_{k=1}^n c_{n,k}aba^kb^k=\sum_{k=1}^n c_{n,k}a(a^kb+[b,a^k])b^k\\ &=\sum_{k=1}^n c_{n,k}a(a^kb+[b,a^k])b^k = \sum_{k=1}^n\left(c_{n,k}a^{k+1}b^{k+1}+kc_{n,k}a^kb^k\right).\end{align*}
This tells us that $(ab)^{n+1}$ can be written in the same form with $$c_{n+1,k}=kc_{n,k}+c_{n,k-1}.$$ We also have the initial condition that $c_{1,1}=1$ and all other $c_{1,k}$'s are zero. These are exactly the initial conditions and recurrence relation for the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) (which I found only by typing the first few $c_{n,3}$'s into the OEIS). They have explicit formulas which are somewhat cumbersome, such as $$c_{n,k}=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{k-i}{k\choose i}i^n.$$
But there are also nice special cases, such as $c_{n,2} = 2^{n-1}-1$ and $c_{n,n-1}={n\choose 2}.$

I think with a small amount of work this can probably be adapted to fit exactly the setting in the question.